# Adding grid when the button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#save2').show();`C#`

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Branch_Audit_Summary.aspx/addempdetails",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        success: function (jsondata) {
            if (jsondata == undefined)
                { return; }
            var data = JSON.parse(jsondata.d);
            var m = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                var rowId = jQuery("#list4").getDataIDs().length;
                jQuery("#list4").addRowData(rowId + 1, data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The grid was not adding when I click.

Comment: Could you post the AJAX log of the request? Do you know if the response is triggering the  `success()` callback?

Comment: Didn't you mean : if (typeof jsondata === 'undefined')   ?

Answer (score 0):

What is jsondata returning...?
What are you sending to the server..? Looks like nothing.

```
    data: "",
```

You should send an error response instead you have

```
if (jsondata == undefined)
                { return; }
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't add comments Mr. Nick Price